# matching between two data frame based on columns

Tags: r

I have two data frames of one row, each data frame has the same columns names.
one of the data frames has NA value in one or more of the columns.
I want to remove the columns that has NA values in one of the data frame and remove the same columns in the second data frame.

sample:

data frame 1:

```
age height education average
 NA  1.80   college    NA
```

data frame 2:

```
age height education  average
 36  1.95   college     85
```

result:

data frame 1:

```
 height education
  1.80   college
```

data frame 2:

```
height education
 1.95   college
```

how do I do this?

Comment: Try `i1 <- !is.na(vector1); vector2[i1]; vector1[i1]`

Comment: @akrun what do I  get in i1?

Comment: You said that you have two vectors.  the `i1` is a logical vector based on the NA elements in first vector

Comment: FYI vectors don't have columns.

Comment: @Sotos I mean data frame of one row..

Comment: @akrun tnx it works!

Comment: If the answer provided by @akrun works, then vector1 & vector2 are indeed 'named vectors' which still don't have columns

Comment: @Sotos i change it to: vector2[,i1] and vector2[,i1] , then it works fine with my data frame of one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like these are data frames, not vectors. If you put them together into the *same* data frame (perhaps with `bind_rows()`), you can use dplyr to handle them all at once and find the columns you want without `NA` values:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
    ~age, ~height, ~education, ~average,
      NA,    1.80,  "college",       NA,
      36,    1.95,  "college",       85
)

df %>% 
    select(which(!colSums(is.na(df))))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   height education
#>    <dbl>     <chr>
#> 1   1.80   college
#> 2   1.95   college
```